# Import DMD file using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

How to import a .dmd file to see the logical & physical diagram in Oracle Sql Developer?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Developer 4:

`File -> Data Modeler -> Open`

should work.